# How to checkout a Pull Request locally using Magit interface?

Tags: magit, git, github

Suppose someone (not me) submitted a Pull Request on GitHub.

Locally, I would like to run that work. Hence, I need to have the code locally. Following [this documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/reviewing-changes-in-pull-requests/checking-out-pull-requests-locally), I **can** achieve that in the terminal with:

```bash
$ git fetch origin pull/ID/head:BRANCH_NAME
```

`ID` is the PR #number on GitHUb. And `BRANCH_NAME` is the branch associated to the PR.

I tried doing the same via Magit interface but had no success.

I tried pressing `f` (associated to command `Fetch`. Then, typing `e` as `elsewhere` and typing  `origin pull/ID/head:BRANCH_NAME` or `origin/pull/ID/head:BRANCH_NAME`. But, it did not work out.

How can I achieve the same via Magit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Execute the instructions below:

1 - execute `f`

2 - press `r` as `explicit refspec`

3 - type origin (since terminal used `origin`, could be another thing...)

4 - type `pull/ID/head:BRANCH_NAME`

Voilà